# Why don't see an error message after this command fails?

Tags: powershell, printing, scripting

I'm trying to print a test page to the default printer in this a small .ps1 script.

```
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" 
$PrintTestPage = $printer.PrintTestPage()
```

For some reason, the test page only actually prints off if I run this command in an admin window. The command seems to complete in a regular non-elevated window, but the printer never actually prints a page, and no error is given. What could be keeping me from printing as a regular user?

EDIT: I tested and it seems to work fine from my laptop or any other machine. What could be making my individual workstation have this problem?

Update: The RMM service I'm using to deploy this script doesn't seem to like the command either, as it won't ever print anything off when being executed. Anyone who knows the cause of this or even a quick fix would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as working on different machines, does the machine the script is not working on have a different version of Powershell?

Comment: Now that you mention it, my workstation is using version 5, and my laptop is running version 4. Was this a change made, or perhaps an error?

Comment: Turns out it's keeping the RMM tool I'm using from printing the page on any of my test machines as well. Erggg!